# RSpec spec_helper access to session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to RoR and Rspec. I am trying to write Rspec tests for a home controller with tests for login and logout etc. I want to be able to login/logout a user using methods from the spec_helper.rb

However when I look at the spec_helper.rb it says it cannot find the session variable or methods like post. Why is this?

Apologies if the question is a little ambiguous. I am not very sure how to frame this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

In RSpec, you can just use:

```
session[:key]
```

However I would suggest reading [RSpec.Info: Controllers](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html) and watching this [Railscast.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec)

Comment: I think sam is specifically asking how to create helper methods in spec_helper.rb for commonly used tasks throughout several controller specs.