# Access session hash in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How can I access the contents of the `session` hash in a request spec?

This (just using `session[:key]`) gave me method undefined:

[RSpec spec_helper access to session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481445/rspec-spec-helper-access-to-session-variable)

Comment: you should post some code: the method you are trying to test, the spec, the full error, this question is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Check that you call session method in right context. You can call it in blocks for methods before, it, specify.

Example:

```
it "should reset session[:auth_by_github]" do
  session[:auth_by_github].should eql(nil)
end
```