# Rspec request specs and session values

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I am writing some request specs (rspec 2.13.1) and would like to directly access the session hash. I think this is syntax is possible in controller specs but not sure if this can can be done in request specs.

```
describe 'Api' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  session[:auth_token]=user.auth_token
```

I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: session[:auth_token]=user.auth_token                              │lock (2 levels) in top_level'                                                         
 NoMethodError:                                                                   │/Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `e
   undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass                                    │ach'                                                                                  
 # ./spec/requests/api_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have seen the following question [Access session hash in request spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555800/access-session-hash-in-request-spec) but not sure if this is accurate.

thx in advance

Comment: Is the test code a copy paste error? You don't have your `session` line inside a test block.

Answer (score 3):

Session data access is intentionally left out of specs when using the `:request` spec type. Generally, this is because it shouldn't be tested directly. You will need to use the older `:controller` type if you want access to session data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several small mistakes

1. You should describe the api_controller
2. Variable assignments for requests should be within an before(:each) block.
3. You are lacking an `it` block
4. When the file is not placed within spec/controllers, you need to specify, that it is a controller test with `:type => :controller`

here is an example of that:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApiController, :type => :controller do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before :each do
    session[:auth_token]=user.auth_token
  end

  it 'should do something' do
    get :index
    response.status.should_not eq 401
  end
end
```

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Seems like there were unfortunate line breaks within the listed points. Adjusted. Thank you.

Comment: I have a doubt: why you set as `:type => controller`? It can't be `:type => request`?

Comment: @RodrigoChaves i believe this may be the case, although i can not confirm this. The test structure has changed within the last years.